# change the quantity of a product during the billing step magento

Tags: magento, billing

I have developed a module that has to change the quantity of a virtual product that is already in cart, during the billing step of checkout.The client that is filling the billing step of checkout, in that step, is good to have the ability to change the quantity ordered with an input field.Does anyone know how to do this?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use another solution in that you can show the cart on checkout either right sidebar or use third party free extension.

https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout-m1.html

To show on right sidebar:

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/local.xml
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```